# Jenkins and Docker integration

Tags: docker, jenkins

Jenkins is doing build and deploy(on tomcat8), so now, how could I make jenkins doing all that stuff in docker?

Jenkins server and Tomcat servers are separated (They are servers one their own)

I made whole work on jenkins. As it is on GitHub, projects are separated in jenkins too(front-end repo and back-end repo). Both are building and deploying by jenkins.

Now, I got task where I need to work with docker too, and I don't understand anything. Is there some plugins in jenkins? Is there some materials for this integrations? I need to make it all work only on one server, not to combine those 2..

I understand how docker works, but I don't know how to integrate this..

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow.   Have you tried a simple enough search for "Jenkins and Docker"?  You might want to do that - in any case; this might be of help to you.

https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/docker/

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find all I need.. I have Jenkins free project for building and deploying Angular6, and Jenkins Maven project for Maven build and deploy. I couldn't find how can I use all work I done and just implement all that in Docker to make Docker deploy it on his tomcat container

Answer (score 1):

You can setup [Docker Containers as build slaves for Jenkins](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/)

Hope this might help you.